# My terminal says i should add a path but i already have (windows 10)

Tags: python, terminal, path

[Terminal warning and Path Variable in system properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYGv8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to restart my terminal and run the following commands:
pip uninstall pipenv
pip uninstall virtualenv
then after adding the path variables I ran :
pip install pipenv.